# Return type of the C function is always an integer while calling it using so file from python

Tags: python, c, linux, ctypes, dynamic-dll-import

I am trying to catch the return value of the function which written in .c file from .py file

Here is my C code snippet and it runs perfectly with main function for itself,

```
float checkRet(){


    float a = 0.34;
    return a;
}
```

and here my python code snippet

```
import ctypes
SoFunc = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('/home/debian/test.so')    
while True:
    print SoFunc.checkRet();
```

and the output I am getting over my screen is

```
-1227793324
```

I want `0.340000` as my output.
Can anyone help me regarding this?

Comment: You have to tell Python what return type the function has: https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/ctypes.html#return-types

Comment: thank you @UnholySheep. It helped me!